# Second Android Native Page focus Issue

Tags: appium, appium-android, nosuchelementexception, appium-desktop

While trying to automate android native application , Appium is not identify or focus on any single element on second page of native application after automating first page login functionality successfully .I have tried with all wait method and driver. context method but it is now working .I have tried to debug the code with so many wait time but it is not working .When i put a break point after automating first page and tried to debug the application then i observed that if i put any manual action on second page (open window and close same window )then appium is allowing to identify the second page also but i didn't understand why it is happening .By automation script, i am unable to do anything on second page .Could any team help me for the same? Page source code for second page :- "

i have tried with below method for identify the second page..

```
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

```
         ICapabilities caps = driver.Capabilities;

         String context = driver.Context;
         Console.WriteLine("Current context", context);
         driver.Context = ("NATIVE_APP");
         String afterloginsource   = driver.PageSource;

         Console.WriteLine("After loginv page source :- ", afterloginsource);

         TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
         t.Tap(100, 100).Perform();

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2400));

         String loginsource = driver.PageSource;

         Console.WriteLine("Befor login page source :- ",loginsource);


         driver.HideKeyboard();
         //enter valid account
         driver.FindElementById("com.Testing:id/userid").SendKeys("00229715");//uat02
        // driver.HideKeyboard();
         /////driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='1']")).SendKeys("17765919"); ////upn02

         ///enter valid password

         driver.FindElementById("com.Testing:id/password").SendKeys("1");

         ///click login button

         driver.FindElementById("com.Testing:id/login").Click();
         driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
         driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200));

         ICapabilities caps = driver.Capabilities;

         String context = driver.Context;
         Console.WriteLine("Current context", context);
         driver.Context = ("NATIVE_APP");
         String afterloginsource   = driver.PageSource;

         Console.WriteLine("After loginv page source :- ", afterloginsource);

         TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
         t.Tap(100, 100).Perform();
AndroidElement expandList = driver.FindElementById("com.Testing:id/btn_more_options");
         expandList.Click();  Or  //((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
         //IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
         //IWebElement hiddenButton = driver.FindElementById("com.Testing:id/enableNotify");
         //String script = "arguments[0].click();";

         //js.ExecuteScript(script, hiddenButton);
```

it is giving error as nosuchelement exception for any element on second page.

Comment: can you run the same tests but with the printPageSourceOnFindFailure capability set to true just to confirm the element is there? Then share the page source?

Comment: After following your valuable suggestion i am not getting any element in page source .please guide me for the same.

Comment: i am getting error- (Message: Test method AndroidAutomationUniTest.TestingApplication.TestingApplicationLoginIssue threw exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/5c3c5532-4b75-4d65-937e-e78e56fb9a66/element timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

)

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElement` states for inability to find the element. It strongly seems for me that xpath locators to webelements on the page are incorrect.

I do recommend to try out [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) just to ensure the locators are organized correctly. And using remote debugging tool - You may also check the locators on-the-fly there.

As an  option B) -  I could also recommend to take a quick glance towards [SeeTest automation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMIUt81GurU) tool. The link above guide on how to set up project from scratch, and here is [public documentation for SeeTest](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Native+Applications+Testing).

Comment: i am not getting no such element exception .when i put debug point with touch action tap method , it is working fine but without debug point it is not allowing to perform any operation on second native page.